# python virtual environments in aws EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

How to have mutiple python virtual environments in an aws EMR cluster . The users will be using Zeppelin or Jupyter for each projects and each project will have different set of python libraries or python versions

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bash script to loop over a map-like structure containing the name of your virtual environment and its libraries (it'll make things easier to maintain if you have multiple projects). The body of the loop will consist of:

1. Create a virtual environment: `virtualenv project_foo`
2. Activate the virtual environment: `source project_foo/bin/activate`
3. Install [ipykernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which provides you with an Ipython kernel for your Jupyter notebook
4. Install your python libraries
5. Add the virtual environment to Jupyter: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=project_foo`
6. Exit the virtual environment: `deactivate`

Now use [Bootstrap Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) to run the script on startup. You should be able to see your virtual environments from the Jupyter's Launcher.

Comment: I did the following in EMR bootstrap program  for 2 virtual environments 
But I am not seeing subproject1 or subproject2 in the EMR notebook

Comment: mkdir -p /mnt/project/project1/subproject1
python3 -m venv /mnt/project/project1/subproject1/

/mnt/project/project1/subproject1/bin/pip install pandas
/mnt/project/project1/subproject1/bin/pip install ipykernel
/mnt/project/project1/subproject1/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=subproject1

Comment: mkdir -p /mnt/project/project1/subproject2
python3 -m venv /mnt/project/project1/subproject2/
/mnt/project/project1/subproject2/bin/pip install matplotlib
/mnt/project/project1/subproject2/bin/pip install ipykernel
/mnt/project/project1/subproject2/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=subproject2

Comment: @RNR What does `/mnt/project/project1/subproject2/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=subproject2` return? Also, it is recommended to source the environment instead of using the full path to execute installation steps.

Comment: I tried that too . I source to the environment and installed it as root .But, In EMR notebook, I see only  Pyspark,Python 3,Sprk,SparkR in kernel